# Laravel: interecept request and change paginate value in Model method?

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel app I have an api entry point where I gather initial data for my app, for example I get pagianted results for posts, tags, users...

I use paginate:15 for all records but for users, I want to use paginate:30, since in my request params I have something like this:

```
page=1&paginate=15
```

is there a way to change it to 30 INSIDE MY CONTROLLER METHOD

InitialController

```
$users = $this->userService->getUsersPaginated($request);
$users = $this->vuePaginate($users);
```

And in my User model:

```
    public function getUsersPaginated($request)
    {
        
        $users = User::
        paginate($request['paginate']);
        


        return $users;
    }
```

Comment: `User::paginate($request['paginate'] * 2)`?

Comment: `$users = User::paginate(30);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate if pagination size can be handled on the frontend side, depending on the *user type*.

Anyway, if you want to handle it on the backend side, you can find a condition that makes you set the pagination size.
For example:

```
if ($currentUser->role == 'final-user')  // or something similar
   $perPage = max (30, $request['paginate']);
else
   $perPage = $request['paginate'];

$users = User::paginate($perPage);
```

I also suggest that you set a minimum and a maximum value for pagination, to avoid wrong values ​​from frontend causing problems (imagine if you get a value like 1,000,000 or -1)

```
const DEFAULT_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 15;
const FINAL_USER_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 30;
const MAX_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 100;

/* ... */

public function getUsersPaginated($request)
{
    $perPage = min (max ($request['paginate'] ?: self::DEFAULT_RESULTS_PER_PAGE, 1), self::MAX_RESULTS_PER_PAGE);

    if (/* condition */)
        $perPage = max (self::FINAL_USER_RESULTS_PER_PAGE, $perPage);

    $users = User::paginate($perPage);

    /* ... */
```

Also note that the default request variable for the paginator is *per_page*